# vimscript - edit another file from a custom command

Tags: vim

I'd like to create, move around and append to other_file.py after calling a custom command from within this_file.py.

So for instance, I'd like to write several lines of text to a range of lines in the other file.

Is there some way I can basically enter :edit mode in other_file.py from this function? This would allow me to move around, search and append to other_file as though I were in it.

Here's a run through of where I'm at:

---

I am in this_file.py, and I have called:

```
:MyComm other_file:line_1/line_2/line_3
```

This activates the following vimscript:

```
function MyFunc(param_string)

    let param_split = split(a:param_string,":")
    let file_name = param_split[0] . ".py"
    let lines = split(class_split[1],"/")

    call system("touch " . file_name)

    " Here is where I want to loop through the lines and use them in other_file.py

endfunction

:command -nargs=1 MyComm :call MyFunc(<f-args>)
```

Answer (score 1):

## alternative A

You can continue going through the external commands, as you've started with `touch`. So, you could use `sed` or `awk` to replace / append lines to the other file. With Vim's `system()` command, you can pass *stdin* input, too. For example, if you want to copy lines from the *current* buffer, grab them with `getline()` and pass them to `system()`, either as a List or a String.

## alternative B

However, I would recommend avoiding external commands, and do the text editing tasks inside Vim. For that you just need to `:execute 'split' other_file`, and do the edits just as you would interactively, using Ex commands or `:normal`. Note that there are some special Ex commands (like `:wincmd w` replacing `<C-w>w` normal mode commands) that can make this more readable.